# java Swing summation of the two columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have made a GUI with Swing which extends Jframe,there are 6 columns in my jtable.I read data
from a text file,in column 4 and column 5 there are values 100 and 200,so i want when user edits in column 4 and puts 160 instead of 100 column 5 automatically changes to 140 or user 
edits in column 5 say 280 instead of 200 column 4 automatically changes to 20.here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

 public class Cs extends JFrame
    {
       private JTable table;
       private DefaultTableModel model;

    public Cs()
   {
      String aLine ;
      Vector columnNames = new Vector();
      Vector data = new Vector();

      try
      {
           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("cs.txt");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));



           StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");

           while( st1.hasMoreTokens() )
           {
                columnNames.addElement(st1.nextToken());
           }



           while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null)
           {
                StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(aLine, " ");
                Vector row = new Vector();

                while(st2.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                     row.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                }
                data.addElement( row );
           }
           br.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }



      model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
      table = new JTable(model);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
      getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
  }

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Cs frame = new Cs();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
     }

   }
```

Comment: Implement this rule in your custom implementation of TableModel. Each time `setValueAt()` changes one column, also change the other. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: So ..go for it.  I see no question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override setValueAt() of your TableModel and update the other column too based on the change. Here is the example. Hope this would help you.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Summation of 2 columns");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Object rows[][] = { { 100, 200 } };

String columns[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };

JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object object, int row, int column) {
        int changedValue = ((Integer) object).intValue();
        if (column == 0) {
            super.setValueAt(300 - changedValue, row, column + 1);
        } else if (column == 1) {
            super.setValueAt(300 - changedValue, row, column - 1);
        }
        super.setValueAt(object, row, column);
    }
});

JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setSize(200, 150);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

You have to change your data model as below to fulfill your requirement.

Replace your model from

```
model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
```

to

```
model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object object, int row, int column) {
        int changedValue = ((Integer) object).intValue();
        if (column == 2) {
            super.setValueAt(300 - changedValue, row, column + 1);
        } else if (column == 3) {
            super.setValueAt(300 - changedValue, row, column - 1);
       }
       super.setValueAt(object, row, column);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you.but i dont understand how to implement it in my code.above is my code and the text file from where i read data into JTable.

Comment: Your code above reads the data from the file and constructs the table model based on that. Just override the setValueAt() for your table and have the business logic in it. If column 3 or column is changed, update the changed value (Say X) in that column and (300 - X) in the other. If the changed column is other than 3 or 4 just set the value of the changed column alone.

Comment: sorry but i am new to swing and it is becoming difficult for me to understand.so could you please kindly elaborate it for me.

Comment: Updated the answer as such. I have hard coded 300 for the summation of 2 columns. You can tweak that based on your need.

Comment: Thank you very much @Loganathan Mohanraj your logic has helped me a lot,but i am finding it difficult to implement it
in my code because i have 8 columns,how to define in which two columns i want to implement this
logic and moreover it is reading data from a text file.i tried implementing your code in my
code but was not able to find a solution.i tried it with two columns and values defined in it
it works fine.but when i tried with 8columns and values reading from text file i find difficult to
understand.

Comment: @Rudydev - The setValueAt() implementation above will work for your case. I have made column 3 & 4 to adjust itself based on the value entered in one of those two column and for the rest of the columns, the value will get updated to the table as you entered. If you want to have 2 different columns to get adjusted automatically, just change the column number in the above code and that it will as expected.

Comment: I have tried as you have told me @Loganathan Mohanraj,as i want column4 and column5
to adjust itself.i have changed if (column==3) else if( column==4),
my program runs without error but when i edit in either of the columns
the adjustment is not made between the two columns.The column i edit changes but the other
column does not change the value automatically.can u please look at my code above and tell me
what changes to be made.

Comment: When i tried @ Loganathan Mohanraj with values defined in the program it works but when i read data from file its showing error.I thing there is some problem with vectors,can u please have a look and help if possible.Please

Comment: I think you have to add integer values to those columns or you have to change the setValueAt() to convert it from to string to integer before manipulating it.

Comment: Can u please give me idea @Loganathan Mohanraj of how to do it.I am stuck with this problem.

Comment: Change you getColumnClass() method of your table to return Integer.class for column 3 and 4

Comment: Thank You @Loganathan Mohanraj your ideas helped me  to solve the problem.thank you so very much for your help

Comment: One last problem @ Loganathan Mohanraj since i have values like 0.0000 and 0.00520 since i returned integer when i edit in jtable a red box appears and other cell cannot be selected unless i make these number as integer.can u give me a solution so that i can get integer as well as float values.

Comment: Change you getColumnClass() method of your table to return Double.class for column 3 and 4

Comment: I have changed the Integer.class part with Double.class the frame opens but with no table in it and when we click on it shows error cannot format given object as a number.

Comment: send me your code and the data file to logumohan@gmail.com. I will fix it and send the code back to you

Comment: can u please check @Loganathan Mohanraj the mail-id u have given because its saying not valid.

Comment: That is a valid email id

Comment: Sorry @Loganathan Mohanraj my mistake.I have mailed you please Check